How to rename internal OS drive without breaking system?
Hey there Ubuntu Community,
I'm in need of some help with the renaming of my internal operating system drive. In Ubuntu 24.04, it seems that the way disks are partitioned and labeled has changed, and I'm no longer able to manually rename them before installing the OS. I've tried using 'disks' and 'gparted', but whenever I change the name it seems to break my system and I cannot boot anymore.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can safely rename my internal OS drive without breaking my system? I'd appreciate any help or guidance you can provide.
Thanks in advance!

Can you explain what you mean by "break my system"?

For example, if I rename the hdd with disks and select "identify as" "LABLE=Linux HD 1" and then reboot the system, I no longer have access to my system and end up with a black screen.

Referencing a partition via its label (note the spelling: LABEL, not LABLE) works, but is not the best method because it can prevent to mount the partition in cause the label changes. The better and more common way is to reference the UUID. Then re-labeling a partition is not a problem.

Are you booting from some other medium (Live USB or your install medium in "Try Ubuntu" mode)? You can only change a disk if NONE of its partitions is mounted.

I've done some further research and have actually solved the problem I was having with my custom disk label name not showing up in the Files (Nautilus) file manager, despite configuring it in Disks or even using tune2fs. Apparently this is hardcoded into Nautilus, and the only way to work around it is to edit the /usr/lib/os-release file to accomplish the name change.
For testing purposes, I changed it to "Linux HD", and as you can see in the screenshot below, after rebooting, Files (Nautilus) shows the name I specified.
It's purely cosmetic and has no effect on UEFI Secure Boot etc. Why the GNOME developers thought this was a good idea, I don't know. It used to be called either "Computer" or "File System".


P.S. I'm puzzled by the downvote on this issue; it's a valid concern, especially in corporate environments where adherence to standard naming schemes is essential for organizational purposes.
